# How often should we use where operator of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this particular scenario where I have to update certain value in MongoDB depending on different attributes present in same Document. So I am trying to use findAndUpdate with where operator which will be passed a JavaScript function and I will also be using one of the attribute as find criteria. But it has been mentioned in MongoDB documentation that, one should not use where operator until it can not be avoided because of performance issue.

Now lets say I have 3 attributes id, counter1, counter2 in my document and I am updating counter1 by 1 only when `counter1 + counter2 = 2`. So I will be writing something like

```
db.mydb.findAndUpdate({"_id" : id, $where : function() { 
                                   this.counter1 + this.counter2 == 2 ;}}, 
                      {$inc : {counter1 : 1}})
```

Now my question is:

1. Will this particular approach create any performance issue? as I am using id as another nonWhere operator criteria to search for a document.
2. Or I should be having another attribute in mydb collection something called say sumCounter which will store the values of counter1 and counter2.

Comment: Very sparingly and preferably only alongside other native query operators that are doing the main filtering. Your query syntax here is not valid BTW. I think you mean: `{ "_id": id, "$where": function() { } }` for it to be valid.

Comment: Yeah, thats right, corrected. Exactly, I am asking as native query operator is the one who is actually doing main filtering, using where operator on top of one single document would make any performance impact ?

Comment: I think you also might mean `this.obj.counter` unless you really mean `this.counter` depending on whether "counter1" is top level or under "obj" like "obj.counter1" in normal queries.

Comment: Any inputs on second part of question ? Whether above query would create any performance impact or not?

Comment: Well that part is called an "answer", which you now have. Of course there is an impact, but it is all relative to what you are actually doing. In this case, the difference is minimal and should be barely noticable.

Comment: Well then if it "solves" the issue then just ["accept"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer. You even have the privelage level now to "upvote" the answer if you are feeling so generous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main catch with [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) evaluation is that the conditional logic cannot process an "index" in order to filter out matches. In addition, it is JavaScript logic afterall, and needs to be compiled as well as there needs to be "object translation" from the native forms into something that will work with the evaluation in the JavacScript engine.

So it's use should be "very sparingly" and only when "absolutely" required, as in there is no other practical way. In your case this is an "update" operation, therefore if you need that logic then fine. If it where just a "query", then I would say to use [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) in the aggregation framework instead:

```js
db.mydb.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": id } } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$eq": [
                    { "$add": [ "$counter1", "$counter2" ] },
                    2
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}        
])
```

As that is at least all in native operators and therefore going to work faster than JavaScript.

As for "performance", then it is all relative. But however in your case where `_id` is a "unique" lookup, then the actual performance "hit" should be negligible as the "exact match" was already done on the "index" for the primary key.

This is the general advice for `$where` conditions. In that you "use them" generally in conjuction with other native query operators that do the "bulk" of the filtering. Then if it takes a few more CPU cycles to apply the conditions in your JavaScript logic ( and it is absolutely needed since there is no other way ), then so be it.

But if however your JavaScript based condition needs to scan many documents without the assistance of other filtering, then that is bad indeed.

Comment: You can also use `$and` in your `if`  to shorten your pipeline to `$redact` only.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, as I have to perform update operation in my case, so I think as per your feedback my solution would work fine. Is there any other way where I can do update operation in more efficient way ?

Comment: @user1776860 No there really isn't another option here. As I mentioned `$where` makes sense in update condtions like this. And it's going to be pretty efficient already with a primary key. The only thing that `$where` should be doing and does already is "filter again" those results already filtered from an index.

Comment: @user3100115 That would actually cause a "huge" performance drop. As I already mentioned here and also to you on another question just recently, the point of the "query" selection is to "use an index" to filter out the content. Which is something `$redact` not `$where` when used by itself can possibly do. That is why the conditions are separated.